# Horizontal Accordion -- trying to use .toggle and .animate

Tags: jquery, accordion, toggle, jquery-animate

Forgive me if this is an inelegant way of going about this but I'm still learning jQuery and am following a path of thought here...

So I started trying to build a horizontal accordion using .toggle and .animate.  Technically, it works...but with one annoying flaw. Here's the scenario:

If I click a box to expand it, then collapse it by clicking another box, that first box I expanded will then require two clicks to expand again.

For example:

1. click box1 to expand it
2. click box2 to expand box2 while collapsing box1
3. box1 will now require two clicks to expand again

Here's the jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/banjodrill/rEPnq/10/

I'm assuming there's some fundamental flaw in the way I'm approaching this.  If anyone has time, I would be grateful if you could take a look and help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Is it related to the fact that I'm using if statements in the toggle functions?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at this:
[jquery_ui_accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

jQueryUI has default stuff for this ;)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I've looked at the UI stuff, I'm just trying to learn the logic behind it.